# What does this Operator mean !!~ in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, operators, operator-keyword

What does this operator `!!~` mean in typescript? Is it a combination of a bitwise operator and NOT operators?

eg `return strict ? term === strValue : !!~strValue.indexOf(term);`

Comment: "*Is it a combination of a bitwise operator and NOT operators?*" yes. `~-1` is `0` so adding `!!` is a way of transforming the "not found" result of `.indexOf()` to `false`.

Comment: instead of using `!!~` which is hard to read, I suggest you to write: `strValue.indexOf(term) >= 0`

Comment: @Yousaf or `strValue.includes(term)`

Comment: @VLAZ yes, that is definitely better since the intention is to return a boolean value.

Comment: thanks guys, i did understand it now. @Yousaf i wasnt using it, i was reading source code and came across this weird operator.